# How to get work days and absence days of an employee (resource)?

Tags: vba, ms-project

How do I get the work and absence days of an employee with VBA from MS-Project? (an employee is a ressource)

Some additional infos:

I know how to get tasks

```vb
Dim ts as Tasks
Set ts = ActiveProject.Tasks
```

and I know how to get ressources from my project file:

```
Dim rs as Resources
Set rs = ActiveProject.ressources
```

but I do not find a (trivial) way to get work and absence days from this variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the Resource object to find the working and non-working days:

```
ActiveProject.Resources.Item(1).Calendar
```

In this trivial example we're picking up the first resource in the project and pulling out it's associated Calendar.

A resource calendar will have a base calendar from which it inherits:

```
...Calendar.BaseCalendar
```

and both the resource calendar and the base calendar define working days, working weeks and exceptions. Exceptions are typically how periods of absence are defined... i.e. they are exceptions to the normal pattern of work:

```
...Calendar.WorkWeeks
...Calendar.WeekDays
...Calendar.Exceptions
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer already provided information to get one started, but does not actually answer the question.  As stated, "Exceptions" are indeed how periods of absence are defined but to determine if a given date is an absence day from the exception object will take a not-insignificant amout of parsing code.

It would be a lot simpler and much more reliable to determine workdays empirically.  Assuming variable "cal" is the calendar in question declare a variable (say "d") of type long  then loop from some start date to some end date-1 and determine if that date is a workday or not using Application.datedifference (d, d+1, cal).  A non work day will yield 0.